# How to define which image is clicked in html page and store the image name in mysql using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, onclicklistener

my project is web image Re-Ranking. I am try to get which image is selected in the html page for update the rank of image in Mysql. My code is

index.php

```
<?php 


 include './search_image.php';

 $obj_image = new Image();

 if(@$_POST['Submit'])
{
$obj_image->image_name=str_replace("'", "''", $_POST['txt_image_name']);

$obj_image->Insert_into_image();

$data_image=$obj_image->get_all_image_list();
$row=mysql_num_rows($data_image);
}

 ?>



  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
   <html>
  <head>
   <title>Home</title>
  </head>
   <body bgcolor=cyan>
   <script>
   window.location.hash="no-back-button";
    window.location.hash="Again-No-back-button";//again because google chrome          don't insert first hash into history
   window.onhashchange=function(){window.location.hash="no-back-button";}
  </script> 
  <center><h1>WEB IMAGE RERANKING</H1></CENTER>
  <center>
  <table border=0 cellspacing=10>
  <th><a href="index.php" target="right">HOME</th>
  <th><a href="admin.php" target"=right">ADMIN</th>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <tr>
   <th width="50%">Enter Image name for search</th>
   <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="txt_image_name"></input></td>
  </tr>
   <td width="50%"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></input>     </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
   </CENTER>




   <?php 
  if($row!=0)
  {
   ?>
  <center>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <table width="30%" border="0"> 
  <?php

     while($data= mysql_fetch_assoc($data_image))
   {
    ?>
   <tr>

    <a href=# onclick="loadImage(String $data['image'])"> <img  src="images/<?php echo $data['image']; ?>"  width="400px" height="200px" ></a>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    </form>
    </center>
   <?php
    } 

    ?>
    <?php
     echo" <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function loadImage(String a) {

      alert('1 %s',a);
     }
     </script>"
     ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

search_image.php

```
   <?php
        include 'db_connection.php' ;

      class Image{

     var 
     $image_id,
       $image_name,
       $image;

      function Insert_into_image(){

         }

        function get_all_image_list(){
       $query = "select *from stor_image where img_name='$this->image_name'";
       $result = mysql_query($query);
       return $result;
       }

       }
       ?>
```

when click on specific image update the rank of the image. So I need help to find image name or src for update the data in mysql database.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 HTML:
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="gallery" id="<?php echo $data['image']; ?>" onClick="reply_click(this.id)"><img  src="images/<?php echo $data['image']; ?>"  width="400px" height="200px" ></a>
 <script>
 function reply_click(clicked_id)
 {
    $imagename=clicked_id;
    alert($imagename);
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HTML:
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="gallery" id="<?php echo $data['image']; ?>"><img  src="images/<?php echo $data['image']; ?>"  width="400px" height="200px" ></a>

JS:
$('.gallery').click(function(){
var image_name = $(this).attr('name');

// make an ajax call with this image name and do what ever you want to do
});
```